# Multiplying 32-bit numbers mod 2³² in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use Excel to multiply 32-bit integers and get the lower 32 bits. In other words given numbers n1, n2, I want to calculate `MOD(n1*n2, 2^32)`. However, this formula doesn't work in Excel because (for larger n1 and n2), the product exceeds Excel's precision capacity and therefore rounds off the lower digits. Is there any way for me to avoid this while still using Excel?

One primitive solution that I managed to come up was just splitting apart one of the numbers into 8-bit chunks and multiplying accordingly (using `MOD` when necessary to truncate), but I'm looking for something less messy, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) you will find that at least since Excel 2007 the following limits have been in place:

> | Feature | Maximum limit |
> | --- | --- |
> | Number precision | 15 digits |
> | Smallest allowed negative number | -2.2251E-308 |
> | Smallest allowed positive number | 2.2251E-308 |
> | Largest allowed positive number | 9.99999999999999E+307 |
> | Largest allowed negative number | -9.99999999999999E+307 |
> | Largest allowed positive number via formula | 1.7976931348623158e+308 |
> | Largest allowed negative number via formula | -1.7976931348623158e+308 |

As you can see you will inevitably loose precision depending on the numbers you're using.

As you specified 32 bit numbers (assuming unsigned integers) the max value you'd need to compute would be 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 (2<sup>32</sup>*2<sup>32</sup> = 2<sup>64</sup>) which clearly exceeds the limit of 15 digits, though it doesn't exceed the limit of the maximum number that can be computed.

In addition you plan to get the lower 32 bits of the result, it would probably be better to resort to an actual programming or scripting language to do such a computation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 64-bit office then you can [create a custom function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) and use the new [`LongLong` type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type) to calculate. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor, click *Insert > Module* then paste the below code

```vb
Public Function MulMod32(number1, number2) As Double
    Dim n1 As LongLong, n2 As LongLong
    n1 = CLngLng(number1)
    n2 = CLngLng(number2)
    
    ' Sign-extend the numbers
    n1 = IIf((n1 And &H80000000&) = 0, n1, n1 Or &HFFFFFFFF00000000^)
    n2 = IIf((n2 And &H80000000&) = 0, n2, n2 Or &HFFFFFFFF00000000^)
    MulMod32 = CDbl((n1 * n2) And &HFFFFFFFF^)
End Function
```

After that you can use `MulMod32()` in any formula, for example `=MulMod32(HEX2DEC("fffffffe"), HEX2DEC("ffff1234"))`

---

If you don't have `LongLong` then you can spit the number into smaller parts to operate on, but you don't need to work on 8-bit chunks because 16-bit values are enough. If we have a and b then after splitting them to (ah, al) and (bh, bl) and their product can be calculated like this

> a × b = (ah × 2<sup>16</sup> + al)(bh × 2<sup>16</sup> + bl) = ah × bh × 2<sup>32</sup> + (ah × bl + al × bh) × 2<sup>16</sup> + al × bl

So we can have 4 columns for ah, al, bh, bl and a column for product with the following formulas

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| ah | =BITRSHIFT(a, 16) |
| al | =BITAND(a, 65535) |
| bh | =BITRSHIFT(b, 16) |
| bl | =BITAND(b, 65535) |
| product | =BITAND(BITAND((ah*bl + bh*al), 65535)*2^16 + al*bl, 4294967295) |

Answer (score 0):

One primitive solution that I managed to come up was just splitting apart one of the numbers into 8 bit chunks and multiplying accordingly (using MOD when necessary to truncate), but I'm looking for something less messy, hopefully.